# Problem with LDR + PIR

Tags: arduino, ldr, pir

I am using a TEMT6000 LDR and a PIR to turn on outdoor lighting, well that's the plan. The LDR and PIR are in the same housing, and after some searching on forums, I found that I can combine the V-wires and G-wires from the PIR and LDR. So my wiring to the board is 2x signal, V and G.

If I don't combine them I need two extra wires. However, I am not really sure this is 'allowed' and/or will mess up my signals? So that would be the first question...

The second one has to do with the LDR reading: Prior to combining the V and G wires as mentioned in the first question, I had the sensors on a breadboard. The reading from the LDR (in low lights?) seems to be pretty unstable, ranging from 0-50 with only light noise from outside. I tried to overcome that by measuring at two intervals of 10 seconds, store these values and divide them by two to get a more balanced reading. Theory was fine but when both measurements are 0, the lights go on... the next reading, 5 seconds later, one of them is 50 and the average is 25... so lights are out again. Is there a way to get a more precise reading from the LDR?

Thanks!

Edit:
In the sensor housing, 2 meters away from the board I have the LDR and PIR connected like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiSOkT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Edit your post to add your circuit diagram and links to datasheet. Maybe you could add more details to your first question too, I have no idea what wires you are talking about.

Comment: What made you think you could share a switched output with an analog output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KTe3.png

Comment: To be honest, I searched for wiring sensors over a longer distance and a discussion about combining V and G in sensors came up where someone shared the V and G lines like I did now. Your question kinda answers mine; it should not be done and each need their own power and ground,so six wires?!

Comment: It's fine to distribute power and ground to the two components from the same power source. Very unlikely to be a problem. The only caution there is if the PIR sensor draws enough power to introduce sag or noise into your power line, that will bleed through into the TEMT6000 circuit.

Comment: tonystewardEE75,  vicatcu -thanks for your replies. Much appreciated. I think I should not combine the power and ground lines if there is a chance of interference then.

Comment: You have to connect all the grounds at least

Comment: PIR sensors only draw micro amps, not a problem at all in terms of sag. The real problem is that CDS photocells are not static or absolute; they have lag, memory and effects from temp. to wit, if you leave one outside all day, and then measure a known value, it will be quite different than a cell of the same batch left in the dark all day before reading. You need to get way less precise in how you tell your program what means light and dark. Also, different CDS have different on resistances, so make sure the other half of your divider matches enough to provide most of the voltage range.

Comment: I did a test with the PIR and LDR... I made a second setup of the whole thingbut with the V and G lines separated. I also used the same PIR and LDR.
The results are the same, used my sketch and a sketch to put out the LDR values. They are the same. 

I've changed the code to do a running average (not sure if that's correct English, I'm Dutch) with twenty samples and 1 second interval, and from that running average I take 2 'final' samples with 15 second interval and divide it by 2. It produces a smoother value to work with, but still testing. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: vicatcu, I use the same PS for the LEDs and the board (5v 30a), so the GNDs are connected.